# PHP/Perl Read File, Refresh when file is updated

Tags: php, perl, file, logging

I've looked all over for how to do this, and I've seen it done in WHM with Jquery and PHP, but how can I have a PHP or Perl script read a log file (logfile.log for example) on a webpage, and refresh as the log file is updated (while staying to the bottom of the log file)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those solutions tend to [`flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) output to the browser as it is happening, rather than building up an output buffer and sending it all in one go.

Comment: See for example the [`tail -f`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) Unix command, and [the related PerlFAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-do-a-tail--f-in-perl%3f)